# API for Organisation Settings -> Security Settings for Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

Do we have API for Organisation Settings (Administrative settings) -> Security Settings for Slack ?

Answer (score 0):

Slack does not have an API to manage Org-wide settings at this time.